# SnapshotTable Data on a daily basis to track change over time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

All

I am looking to create a query that will run on a daily basis and will collect the values retained in a given field.

The purpose of this exercise is to complete, what I call, "white space analysis". Against each company entity we should have a record of their existing solution in 10 key portfolio areas. The aim of the game is to remove the white space from the entity.

A row will be created per Record Owner and will be date stamped with the datye that the query is being run. additional columns will count the number of fields that have received an entry.

This should allow me to work out how may things each account manager knows about their customer base and track movements over time.

The query would need to create a new line for each day we run the query allowing me to count change over time.

This is my target table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfileScore](
[Date] [date] NULL,
[owneridname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Cyber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Encryption] INT NULL,
[Firewall] INT NULL,
[PCIDSS] INT NULL,
[asvscanner] INT NULL,
[pentest] INT NULL,
[phish] INT NULL,
[Scanner] INT NULL,
[TwoFactor] INT NULL,
[customertype] INT NULL,
```

Source Data looks like this

```
owneridname cyber   encryption  firewall    pcidss  asvscanner  pentest phish   scanner twofactor   customertype
Dave NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
Dave NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
CRMSERVICE  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
Joey NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
Daniel NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
CRMSERVICE  NULL    NULL    No Opportunity  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
Kenny NULL  NULL    WatchGuard  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
Daniel NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
Matt NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
CRM Guest 01    NULL    NULL    NULL    No  -- Not Applicable --    Yes NULL    NULL    NULL    Customer
```

Results table...
I would like a row per Owner for each given date.
Each column would then count the number of NOT NULL entries each Owner has in the records against their name.
The final column simply counts the number of records each Owner has

```
where customertype = 'Customer

DROP TABLE mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable(
owneridname  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,cyber        VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
,encryption   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
,firewall     VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
,pcidss       VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
,asvscanner   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,pentesting   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
,phishin      VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
,scanner      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
,twofactor    VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
,customertype VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);
     INSERT INTO mytable   (owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Dave',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,'No','-- Not Applicable --',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Dave',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Joey',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'No Opportunity',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Kenny',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE','In Action',NULL,NULL,'No','-- Not Applicable --','Yes',NULL,'AppCheck',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Guest 01',NULL,NULL,NULL,'No','-- Not  Applicable --','Yes',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Joey',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Guest 01',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Joey',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Luke','Not Interested',NULL,'WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --','No','No - Not Interested','In Process','#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Kenny',NULL,'Other',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Joey',NULL,'None','WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --','No',NULL,'None',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Asa',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,'Juniper','No','-- Not Applicable --','Yes',NULL,'None','#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,'Cisco',NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,'AppCheck',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Adam',NULL,NULL,NULL,'No',NULL,'Yes',NULL,'AppCheck',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Gareth','Not Interested','Other',NULL,'Yes',NULL,'Yes',NULL,NULL,'#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Gareth',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Kenny',NULL,NULL,NULL,'No','-- Not Applicable --','Yes',NULL,'None',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Adam',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Scott',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Luke','Not Interested',NULL,'No Opportunity','No','-- Not Applicable --','No','No - Not Interested','In Process','#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Gareth',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('James',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Scott',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Dave','Not Interested',NULL,'Cisco','Yes','-- Not Applicable --','Yes',NULL,'Nessus',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Gareth','Not Interested','None','WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --','No','No - Not Interested',NULL,'#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'SonicWALL',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Dave',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Adam','In Action',NULL,'Palo Alto','Yes',NULL,'Yes',NULL,'AppCheck','#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,'BeCrypt','Stonesoft StoneGate','Yes',NULL,'Yes',NULL,'None','VASCO','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Lisa Copley',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --','Yes',NULL,'None','RSA','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'Check Point',NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Adam',NULL,'PGP','WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --','No',NULL,'None',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Joey',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Stephanie',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'No',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'No Opportunity',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Gareth','Not Interested',NULL,'Sophos','Yes',NULL,'Yes','No - Not Interested',NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Alex Evans',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'Microsoft ISA',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Kenny',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,'WatchGuard',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Gareth','Not Interested',NULL,'WatchGuard','No','-- Not Applicable --','In Process',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Matt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Daniel',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,'Yes',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Ryan',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE','Unkown',NULL,'DrayTek',NULL,NULL,'No',NULL,'None','#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'Sophos',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRMSERVICE',NULL,NULL,'SonicWALL',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Other','#NAME?','Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('Emma',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Yes',NULL,'Yes',NULL,'Nessus',NULL,'Customer');
    INSERT INTO mytable(owneridname,cyber,encryption,firewall,pcidss,asvscanner,pentesting,phishin,scanner,twofactor,customertype) VALUES ('CRM Support',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Customer');
```

Any ideas would be very welcome indeed.

Comment: some example explanations using some data with expected results will be more helpfull

Comment: please look here on how to improve question ,https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: sorry, it was a bit messy. I've updated the main entry @thegameiswar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
select getdate(), owneridname, count(cyber), count(encryption),
count(1) totalentries
from sourcedata
group by owneridname
```

I've only included cyber and encryption as an example but you can complete the counts for the other areas too